# can ticking checkbox update javascript function call arguments? 

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have **few pairs** of button & check box like on my pages (the **combination** of the first two arguments in this examole it's 'login' & 'basics' is **unique** for each button(

```
<button class="square_button button_background" type="button" 
           onclick="run_through_ajax('login','basics','false')"> run </button>
<input name="restore" title="restore before ant run" type="checkbox">
```

Can I somehow

- update `onclick="run_through_ajax('login','basics','false')"` to onclick="run_through_ajax('login','basics','**true**')" once the checkbox is **ticked**?
- updated `onclick="run_through_ajax('login','basics','true')"` to onclick="run_through_ajax('login','basics','**false**')" once the checkbox is **un-ticked**
- can I achieve that **without introducing ID's** for every single button? Can I 'wrap/group' button and checkbox in div so I know what to update?

I can use jQuery, doesn't have to be pure javascript solution.

Every 'run' button runs javascript with different parameters. The checkbox is there to distinguish if one extra action needs to be performed before the `run`.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How 'bout this?

**HTML**:

```
<input type="hidden" value="login|basic"></input>
<button class="square_button button_background" type="button"> run </button>
<input name="restore" title="restore before ant run" type="checkbox">
<input type="hidden" value="test|advanced"></input>
<button class="square_button button_background" type="button"> run </button>
<input name="restore" title="restore before ant run" type="checkbox">
<input type="hidden" value="login|basic"></input>
<button class="square_button button_background" type="button"> run </button>
<input name="restore" title="restore before ant run" type="checkbox">
```

**Javascript**:

```
function run_through_ajax(p1, p2, p3)
{
    console.log('p1: '+p1+', p2: '+p2+', p3: '+p3);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button[type=button]').click(function(e){
        var params = $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val();
        run_through_ajax(params.split('|')[0], params.split('|')[1], false);
    });
});

$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e){
    $(this).prev('button').unbind('click');
    $(this).prev('button').click(function(){
        var params = $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val();
        run_through_ajax(params.split('|')[0], params.split('|')[1], e.currentTarget.checked);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbrecht/jpySU/

The only dependency here is that the button that you want to toggle the parameter for is the previous button element in the page.

Comment: Is there a reason *why* you want the `onclick` there? If there's an actual *need* for it, you could always remove the `onclick` attribute of the button prior to binding it via jQuery..

Comment: I updated my question. Picture that hopefully explains a lot + two sentences above the pic.

Comment: @radek: Updated my answer and fiddle. Maybe not the *nicest* solution, but I'm running out the door and it's the one I could come up with the quickest :)

Comment: exactly what I wanted !!! Thank you. I didn't know I can do the call your way. I like it better this way.

Comment: one more question: what does `$('button[type=button]')` mean? the first button is text or class or ... ? how can I make 100% sure that only these 'run' buttons trigger the run_through_ajax function and not any other button?

Comment: It's just the selector that I used. If you want to make *sure* that only the run buttons are used, you could assign a class to each button (i.e. `run`) and use that in your selector: `button[type=button] .run`. Really, `type=button` is a little redundant, but is explicit.

Comment: I crated new question for that one....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184090/why-does-next-give-me-undefined