# why does .next() give me 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

why does .next() returns 'undefined'? http://jsfiddle.net/radek/sD6JB/2/

**html**

```
<button value="login|basic" class="square_button button_background" type="button"> run </button>
<input name="restore" title="restore before ant run" type="checkbox">

<button value="test|advanced" class="square_button button_background" type="button"> run </button>
<input name="restore" title="restore before ant run" type="checkbox">

<button value="best|4444" class="square_button button_background" type="button"> run </button>
<input name="restore" title="restore before ant run" type="checkbox">

<div id='results'/>
```

**javascript + jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button[type=button]').click(function(){
        var params = $(this).val();
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML+=
          "<BR>"+params.split('|')[0]+" - "
           + params.split('|')[1]+" - "
           + $(this).next().checked;
     });
});
```

Comment: Why do you even have `<button type="button">` tags in the first place? Buttons *are* buttons.

Comment: "Buttons _are_ buttons." lol!

Comment: @BoltClock The default `type` attribute of `button` is `submit`. [Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5).

Comment: why? bacause of that http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Comment: all great answers and withing 2 minutes of posting my question ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A jQuery object has no `checked` property.

You can either...

(a) Subscript the native DOM element with `[0]` or `get(0)`.

(b) Access `prop('checked')` (>= jQuery 1.6 only.)

(c) Use `is(':checked')`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're calling `.checked` on the jQuery object and not the DOM element. If you want to call `.checked` you need to get the DOM element out of the jQuery collection.

Simply changing that line to the below will work

```
$(this).next().get(0).checked
```

Fixed fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sD6JB/3/

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It is `undefined` because, when you are in the `click` function `$(this)` set only holds one element, on which you define the `click` property. So there is no next sibling in the set.</strike>

<strike>**Explanation:**</strike>

<strike>`$('button[type=button]')` holds all `button` elements with `type=button` attribute.
When you define clickhandler on them, you create a function for each, and in that function `this` will be the element, on which you define the event handler.
When you the use `$(this)` you create a jQuery wrapper set, that contains only this element.
`.next()` is used to select the next sibling in the set, but your set has only one element.</strike>

<strike>**Solution:**</strike>

<strike>$(this).siblings("input").is(":checked")</strike>

Btw, using checked is also a problem, but your initial undefined problem's cause is the above.
Use `.is(":checked")` instead.

Comment: I don't understand this answer :-)

Comment: works nicely, thank you. Now I even understood what you meant :-)

Comment: Sorry but my solution is wrong after, I just tested it. :( Striked the false part. `.next()` works as you expect, just use the other methods to test if it is checked.